# What is the simplest Java framework to implement Master - Slave architechure?

Tags: java, rpc

I am building an application where the basic architecture follows the Master - Slave idea. There is a lot of control information that flows from Master to Slave and back. In addition to this, Slaves share bulk data among each other.

I was thinking of having RPC, but I was suggested that they might give suboptimal performance because of their http dependencies. (Not that performance is my priority :-)). I am looking for a simplistic framework (RPC would work too, if it is good idea).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Application: I am trying to build something similar (but without the reliability part) to Pregel for a course project. Sockets + RPC initially seemed like a good idea, but now I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try RMI, which doesn't use HTTP.  It is fairly simple to use and you should be able to achieve 2000 requests per second for modest requests.

Comment: RMI would be my suggestion too. You will have to wade through some command-line vodoo though, but there's a lot of tutorials about RMI online.

Comment: Using maven/ant/ide plugins can make this easier.